# How to find time in Avl Trees?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

An operation for an application that uses an AVL-tree is of O(log N) time. It takes about 50
milliseconds to run on a collection of 10,000 elements. How long would you expect it would
take to run on a collection of 100,000 elements?

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't guess the time it would take to make it run on a larger collection, because you have to take into account all the constant computation costs of your application (i.e. loading, preprocessing etc...).

However, you can find an upper bound: log(10000) = 4, log(100000) = 5, so you could expect it to run in less than 5/4 * 50 = 62.5 ms, provided you already reached the asymptotic behaviour.

Anyway, O(log N) is a very efficient complexity, your algorithm should scale very well to big instances.

Comment: I have to add that other seem to have understood a complexity of O(N log N) instead of O(log N), which is the usual complexity for a query in a sorted tree (eg a map in c++).

Moreover the base of the logarithm does not change anything, as it is taken into account in the big O notation. (log n = ln n / ln 10)

Answer (score 0):

To treat N elements, you need approximate time

```
T ~ C * N * log (N)
```

for 10000:

```
 50 ms =  C * 10^4 * log(10^4) = C * 4 * 10^4 * log(10)
 C = 50ms / (4 * 10^4 * log(10))
```

for 100000:

```
T ~ 50ms / (4 * 10^4 * log(10)) * 5 * 10^5 * log(10)
T ~ 50ms  * 5 * 10 / 4 = 625 ms
```

So you would expect time about 625 ms